# WordPress CPT Taxonomy Display all Posts in Taxonomy Category Page

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy-terms

I have CPT called "Trial" and a Taxonomy "Trial-Category" - template name = taxonomy-trial-category.php using the standard loop. I can't get it output all the posts. In Settings > Reading - I've set it to display 50. I've used this function which doesn't work either:

```
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'spigot_show_all_work' );
function spigot_show_all_work( $query ) {   
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {    
        if ( is_post_type_archive( 'trial' ) ) {
            $query->set('posts_per_page', -1 ); 
        }
    }
}
```

My Loop in in my template file is:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="trial-info">
        <h3><a title="<?php the_title();?>" href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h3>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

It will only display 10 posts no matter what I've tried.

My Register CPT:

```
    add_action( 'init', 'create_trial_post_type' );

function create_trial_post_type() {
    $args = array(
                  'description' => 'Trial Post Type',
                  'show_ui' => true,
                  'menu_position' => 4,
                  'exclude_from_search' => false,
                  'labels' => array(
                                    'name'=> 'Clinical Trials',
                                    'singular_name' => 'Clinical Trials',
                                    'add_new' => 'Add New Trial',
                                    'add_new_item' => 'Add New Trial',
                                    'edit' => 'Edit Trial',
                                    'edit_item' => 'Edit Trial',
                                    'new-item' => 'New Trial',
                                    'view' => 'View Trials',
                                    'view_item' => 'View Trial',
                                    'search_items' => 'Search Trials',
                                    'not_found' => 'No Trials Found',
                                    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Trials Found in Trash',
                                    'parent' => 'Parent Trial'
                                   ),
                 'public' => true,
                 'capability_type' => 'post',
                 'hierarchical' => true,
                 'has_archive' => true,
                 'rewrite' => true,
                 'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt')
                 );
    register_post_type( 'trial' , $args );
}

/*====================================================
Register Custom Taxonomies
======================================================*/

add_action('init', 'register_trial_taxonomy');

function register_trial_taxonomy() {
  register_taxonomy('trial-category',
                    'trial',
                     array (
                           'labels' => array (
                                              'name' => 'Trial Categories',
                                              'singular_name' => 'Trial Categories',
                                              'search_items' => 'Search Trial Categories',
                                              'popular_items' => 'Popular Trial Categories',
                                              'all_items' => 'All Trial Categories',
                                              'parent_item' => 'Parent Trial Category',
                                              'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Trial Category:',
                                              'edit_item' => 'Edit Trial Category',
                                              'update_item' => 'Update Trial Category',
                                              'add_new_item' => 'Add New Trial Category',
                                              'new_item_name' => 'New Trial Category',
                                            ),
                            'hierarchical' =>true,
                            'show_ui' => true,
                            'show_tagcloud' => true,
                            'rewrite' => true,
                            'public'=>true
                            )
                     );
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you register the custom post type? Or is it created by plugin?

Comment: Have you debugged it to confirm that spigot_show_all_work is being called and `if ( is_post_type_archive( 'trial' ) ) {` is getting triggered?

Comment: I updated the above w/the register of CPT + Taxonomy. @FluffyKitten you are correct, the Spigot isn't working. Still not sure what route to take.